# Practical Difference Between Type and Class in Scala

Tags: class, scala, types

What is practical difference between

```
class person(val name: String, val weight: Int)
```

and

```
type person = (String,Int)
```

?

Comment: I would upgrade a type alias to a (case) class if the `._1` and `._2` appeared so many times that nobody could understand those magic numbers mean.

Answer (score 1):

Type aliases are just aliases. They're substituted (resolved) at compile time and do not exists further. As a result, there no way to reference them from, say, java code.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it means to compare a tuple with class person. From my understanding, there maybe no comparison. Probably this example should looks like this ?

```
class Person(val name: String, val weight: Int)

type P = Person
```

so P is just alias of Person in this case, nothing fancy.

I assume that you maybe little confused that what we gained if we use "type". From my knowledge, there are several scenarios which make the keyword "type" very useful.

1. Cake pattern or stackable trait

> trait Like {  type T }
>
> trait PersonLike extends Like {  override type T = Person }

1. If the type is too complicated, you can shortcut it

> type T = (Int => Int) => (String => String)

Anyway, I am not sure this clarify your confusion.